# How can I set the webpack --mode using webpack-dev-middleware?

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-4

I have an express server that runs my app using `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-dev-server`.

After updating to webpack@4.1.1 I get the following warning

```
WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.
```

Since I am not directly running webpack from the CLI how can set the --mode option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mode` option can also be set in the webpack config object:

```
{
    mode: 'development'
}
```

More related info configuring **Webpack 4** can be found in this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo)